# Django: How to define a dynamic initial value on a ForeignKey Model Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can one define a dynamic initial value on a foreign key field?

With the code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Example(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, initial=settings.SITE_ID)
```

I've the following error:

```
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, initial=settings.SITE_ID)
Field.__init__(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
```

I also tried with:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, initial=Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model fields don't take an "initial" parameter, they take "default".

Comment: Right! While looking around, I started with Model.default and ended in Field.initial, and I mixed them up.
My problem was actually elsewhere but thanks anyway you helped me to find the solution.
It seems one cannot define a dynamic default value in a new model then do a syncdb. So I had to remove the default param, do the syncdb, then add the default in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `save()` method of the model and check if the field's value is `None`.

Comment: Thanks. It could do the job but I want to display a default value in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right about the *dynamic* part, this is related to a [Django foreign key FAQ](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/), and James Bennett's [Django tips: auto-populated fields](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/02/django-tips-auto-populated-fields/) (see **The Holy Grail** subhead :-).

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it to be automatically populated, I want users to be able to select another value than the default one.